# Typescript discriminated unions in an object depending on string

Tags: typescript

I initially thought my problem would be solved by conditional types, but upon further inspection it seems like discriminated unions would work better for my case.

[These examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) get really close to what I want, but I'm still confused on how to implement it in my real world example.

Say I have an interface, in this case it's the data I get back after logging in with Passport.js:

```js
export interface UserInterface {
  id: number
  username: string
  photos: {
    values: string
  }[]
  provider: 'twitter' | 'github'
  _json: TwitterProfileInterface | GithubProfileInterface
}
```

In the above, `id`, `username` and `photos` are all interchangeable. However, the type of `_json` depends on the value of `provider`. So if `provider` is `twitter`, then `_json` will be `TwitterProfileInterface`.

Is there any way to make this automatic with Typescript?

EDIT: Example code:

I'm running a switch statement to check what type of User Profile I received:

```
const user = {
  id: 1,
  username: "User",
  photos: [],
  provider: "twitter",
  _json: {
    // a bunch of data specific to the "twitter" provider
  }
};

switch(user.provider){
  case 'twitter':
    // this case will give types from both TwitterProfileInterface and GithubProfileInterface
    break;
  case 'github':
      // this case will give types from both TwitterProfileInterface and GithubProfileInterface
    break;
}
```

Even though I have a switch statement, the fact that the value I use for the switch is contained outside of either `TwitterProfileInterface` and `TwitterProfileInterface` then both cases will include both types, rendering my types pointless.

Comment: I don't see much of a use for conditional types here; this looks more like you need a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), such as [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXR1Dm) for example. Does that meet your needs?  If so, could you maybe edit the question to remove the dependency on conditional types?  If not, could you elaborate in your question what those needs are?  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz That does look more like what I want to do, but how do I make it so the type is decided outside of my union?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  What does "type is decided outside of my union" mean?  Could you show me with a [mcve]?

Comment: Is the example in the OP not enough? In my case the "switch" (`provider`) is not contained within the two types I'm switching between unlike the Typescript example. So while I can use a Switch Statement with `provider` I don't see how that will have effect on which `_json` type I use.

Comment: It might be enough for someone else, but not for me, sorry.  Ideally you'd write some example code with the `switch` statement in question and so I could see for myself what issue you're running into.  If you use [this union](https://tsplay.dev/wXR1Dm), what specific code are you having trouble writing?

Comment: I've edited my question with the specific code, let me know if that makes sense

Comment: It seems you've already accepted an answer that isn't using discriminated unions... if you're interested, the discriminated union version looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL9raW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional type and parameter, like this:

```
interface TwitterProvider { foo: number }
interface GithubProvider { foo: string }

export type UserInterface<P extends 'twitter' | 'github'> = {
  id: number
  username: string
  photos: {
    values: string
  }[]
  provider: P
  _json: P extends 'twitter' ? TwitterProvider : P extends 'github' ? GithubProvider : {}
}

let foo: UserInterface<'twitter'> = {
  id: 1,
  username: 'foo',
  photos: [{values: 'foo'}],
  provider: 'twitter',
  _json: { foo: 1 }
}
```

[**Live, Interactive Example**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHdhklAClAewDdgATaZAb2RgIIC5kQBXAWwCMKBfAKFB3hJkAcSwALZu3zEyFarQbIAzmCigA5sl48IADwAOBKGGRgAnvpQBVJdACS4aIIgAeXMj2QQpJcgDkYJjY0H7IAD7+6uKSfgB8yAC8VDzIyGSMLBzQKcjMtlAgcKwQjCpqIOo5+mIEYARKjJQ5qURwADbMEA3Kqho5XADaALpVhCTkUIy4OQD6AFZKBCBTHrpePv6BWDihAPxoQTjS4xQrnhDevn5RYBLseyLRUmOyUMiNvNptECYKjDb2RywRCuAKHELxJJNVLpZAARgANDk8tBCsVGH4FH4kalqrV6owBpRWh0uhisVwhjjkPoXhMMVtglBsbMFktGjQ6Iw4VoeFwgA)

Comment: How does this work for the interface? Typescript is throwing errors if I stick this in `PassportUserInterface`

Comment: Oooooh, I see how this works now. That's really helpful!

Comment: If you want to add a fallback, change the `: {}` to `: FallbackType`. To add more options, add another chain and change the `extends '...' | '...'` directive.